# Пути в файле index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apache

Сделал проект на vue, отлаживал, используя встроенный сервер npm run serve. Хочу разместить на апаче (еще не разу не делал). Набрал команду build, содержимое полученной папки dist разместил в каталоге WWW/MyFirstProject. Работает, если только в файле index.html ко всем путям дописать 'MyFirstProject/'. Как сделать, что бы каждый раз c этим не морочиться?

Comment: В апаче необходимо конфигурить mod_rewrite. (и прописывать RewriteRule в .htaccess). В интернете инфы полно

Comment: Благодарю за направление, будем изучать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Залейте все из директории MyFirstProject в директорию www и будет вам счастье =)

чтобы было не `www/MyFirstProject/файлы самого проекта`

а так: `www/файлы самого проекта`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но есть нюансик, там предполагается наличие и других проектов.

Comment: У Вас это просто хостинг или VPS ?  
Если обычный хостинг, он создает под каждый домен свою директорию с www  - типа /domains/your_domain.com/public_html/www/ сюда ваш код проекта.

Если VPS там уже как сами настроите. Например можно в Nginx указать путь к конкретному сайту и не важно где ваш сайт находится на сервере.